# How do you deploy a MVC4 .net app to production WITHOUT Web Deploy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, microsoft-web-deploy

I'm trying to deploy one of the default template apps that VS2012 generates for MVC4 to a production server (not on Azure).

It turns out that I'm not smart enough to figure out how to get Web Deploy working. After spending an hour on diagnosing different 404s, 403s, and 401s, I am ready to either ditch Web Deploy altogether, or start my project using PHP instead.

Can I just copy and paste my files and put them somewhere?

I'm fine with manually updating the database schema.

Anything else that needs to be updated?

Comment: You can copy/paste, but you'll likely end up with stuff you don't want (.cs files, etc).  Have you looked into just creating a simple build script that copies the files you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can publish directly to "File System" via "Publish" menu in VS (choose folder on production server). Then create WebApp on IIS with this folder (on the server) choose ApplicationPool 4.0 open port for your application if needed and start it.

Answer (score 1):

What in the world makes you even think you need to use web deploy?  You do realize that the web publishing wizard has several options to choose from, including FTP, file system, etc... I don't see how you could miss these.

[image]

Comment: VS2012 doesn't have that dropdown.

Comment: @JohnShedletsky - Yes, it does.  In fact, that picture is from VS2012.  See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ikh9tJw6Zo4